# Linq to entities Left Join

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, left-join, outer-join

I want to achieve the following in Linq to Entities:

Get all Enquires that have no Application or the Application has a status != 4 (Completed)

```
select e.*
from Enquiry enq
left outer join Application app
 on enq.enquiryid = app.enquiryid
where app.Status <> 4 or app.enquiryid is null
```

Has anyone done this before without using DefaultIfEmpty(), which is not supported by Linq to Entities?

I'm trying to add a filter to an IQueryable query like this:

```
IQueryable<Enquiry> query = Context.EnquirySet; 

query = (from e in query 
         where e.Applications.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             .Where(app=>app.Status != 4).Count() >= 1 
         select e);
```

Thanks 
Mark

Comment: For what it's worth DefaultIfEmpty is included in EF .NET 4.0.

Comment: Thanks Damien - looking forward to the EF enhancements in .NET 4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
IQueryable<Enquiry> query = Context.EnquirySet; 

query = (from e in query 
         where (!e.Applications.Any()) 
               || e.Applications.Any(app => app.Status != 4)
         select e);
```

I don't find LINQ's handling of the problem of what would be an "outer join" in SQL "goofy" at all. The key to understanding it is to think in terms of an object graph with nullable properties rather than a tabular result set.

Any() maps to EXISTS in SQL, so it's *far* more efficient than Count() in some cases.

Answer (score 10):

In EF 4.0+, LEFT JOIN syntax is a little different and presents a crazy quirk:

```
var query = from c1 in db.Category 
        join c2 in db.Category on c1.CategoryID equals c2.ParentCategoryID  
        into ChildCategory 
        from cc in ChildCategory.DefaultIfEmpty() 
        select new CategoryObject  
        { 
            CategoryID = c1.CategoryID,  
            ChildName = cc.CategoryName 
        }
```

If you capture the execution of this query in SQL Server Profiler, you will see that it does indeed perform a LEFT OUTER JOIN. HOWEVER, if you have multiple LEFT JOIN ("Group Join") clauses in your Linq-to-Entity query, I have found that the self-join clause MAY actually execute as in INNER JOIN - EVEN IF THE ABOVE SYNTAX IS USED!

The resolution to that? As crazy and, according to MS, wrong as it sounds, I resolved this by changing the order of the join clauses. If the self-referencing LEFT JOIN clause was the 1st Linq Group Join, SQL Profiler reported an INNER JOIN. If the self-referencing LEFT JOIN clause was the LAST Linq Group Join, SQL Profiler reported an LEFT JOIN.

Comment: this answer should really get more karma

Answer (score 3):

Thanks guys for your help. I went for this option in the end but your solutions have helped broaden my knowledge.

```
IQueryable<Enquiry> query = Context.EnquirySet;

query = query.Except(from e in query
                     from a in e.Applications
                     where a.Status == 4
                     select e);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of Linq's goofy (read non-standard) way of handling outers, you have to use DefaultIfEmpty().

What you'll do is run your Linq-To-Entities query into two IEnumerables, then LEFT Join them using DefaultIfEmpty().  It may look something like:

```
IQueryable enq = Enquiry.Select();
IQueryable app = Application.Select();
var x = from e in enq
join a in app on e.enquiryid equals a.enquiryid
into ae
where e.Status != 4
from appEnq in ae.DefaultIfEmpty()
select e.*;
```

Just because you can't do it with Linq-To-Entities doesn't mean you can't do it with raw Linq.

(Note: before anyone downvotes me ... yes, I know there are more elegant ways to do this.  I'm just trying to make it understandable.  It's the concept that's important, right?)

Comment: Is that possible when I'm filtering the IQueryable<Enquiry> results in order to create a stored expression like this do you know?:

IQueryable<Enquiry> query = Context.EnquirySet;

query = (from e in query
         where e.Applications.DefaultIfEmpty().Where(app=>app.Status != 4).Count() >= 1
 select e);

Comment: Hmmm can't seem to get this working in my example. Are you sure the where clause is correct? Status is on the app Entity???

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to consider, if you directly reference any properties in your where clause from a left-joined group (using the into syntax) without checking for null, Entity Framework will still convert your LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN.

To avoid this, filter on the "from x in leftJoinedExtent" part of your query like so:

```
var y = from parent in thing
        join child in subthing on parent.ID equals child.ParentID into childTemp
        from childLJ in childTemp.Where(c => c.Visible == true).DefaultIfEmpty()
        where parent.ID == 123
        select new {
            ParentID = parent.ID,
            ChildID = childLJ.ID
        };
```

ChildID in the anonymous type will be a nullable type and the query this generates will be a LEFT JOIN.